# How can I convert a double into HH:MM:SS in ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, datetime, converters, nsdateformatter

I've got a double 0.27392 and I know it is 6:34:27 AM. This is simple in Excel, but I can't get NSDateFormatter to work its magic.

Comment: That’s a strange double time. I thought that dates stored as doubles are simply the number of seconds elapsed from some reference date. If this was the case, your double would not even be a single second and could only represent 6:34:27 AM if measured from 6:34:27 AM :-)

Comment: Yeah a date stored as a double is a NSTimeInterval wich is the number of seconds from a given reference date. The standard reference date is the first instance of "1 January 2001, GMT". "1 January 1970, GMT" is also used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh OK, great catch zoul.

In that case i would do:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

double time = 0.27392;
double timeInSeconds = time*24*60*60; // 0.27392 * 24 = 6.57408 hours *60 for minutes * 60 for seconds

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeInSeconds]; //Creates a date: 1 January 2001 6:34:27 AM, GMT

NSLog(@"Time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Yes, that’s better, it’s always a good idea not to invent the date formatting stuff yourself (too easy to miss something).

Comment: Both correct answers and I wish I can give it to both, but I was looking for the NSDateFormatter answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see. That’s the number of hours elapsed since the start of the day. In that case:

```
double time = 0.27392;
double timeInHours = time*24; // 6.57408
int hours = (int) timeInHours; // 6
int minutes = (timeInHours - floor(timeInHours)) * 60; // 0.57408*60=34.4448 → 34
```

…and so on.